# Receiving JSON through Serial COM Port in Python

Tags: python, json, tkinter, serial-port, pyserial

I want to receive a JSON file from the serial COM port and show some part of this data on my Tkinter Canvas Text Labels but I have some problems.

I have Tkinter GUI which has Canvases and some canvas.create_text() in it. I want to show a specific field of JSON (like json_data["PersonnelFoods"][0]) on these labels.

the JSON example:

```
{
  "CurrentDateTime": "19:33 2021/09/09 wednedsday",
  "CurrentMealRemainTime": {
    "Ticks": 96350000000,
    "Days": 0,
    "Hours": 2,
    "Milliseconds": 0,
    "Minutes": 40,
    "Seconds": 35
  },
  "RemainFoods": [
    { "Title": "a", "Remain": 123, "Total": 150 },
    { "Title": "b", "Remain": 13, "Total": 200 },
    { "Title": "c", "Remain": 250, "Total": 350 }
  ],
  "PersonnelFoods": [
    {
      "FullName": "A",
      "PersonnelNumber": "324354",
      "Meal": "B",
      "Shift": "C",
      "Company": "D",
      "MainFoods": [
        { "Des_Food": "E", "Num_Amount": "1", "Typ_Serv_Unit": "F" }
      ],
      "SubsidiaryFoods": [
        { "Des_Food": "F", "Num_Amount": "1", "Typ_Serv_Unit": "H" },
        { "Des_Food": "I", "Num_Amount": "1", "Typ_Serv_Unit": "J" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Python code:

```
from tkinter import *
from serial import *
import JSON

ser = Serial(port='COM10', baudrate=115200, timeout=1)

data = ""
json_data = ""
def readport():
    global data
    global final_data
    a = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
    data = data + a
    with open("data.json",'w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(data)
    root.after(10, readport)

def readjson():
    global json_data
    with open("data.json",encoding='utf-8') as fr:
        readed_file = fr.read()
        json_data = json.loads(readed_file)
        myCanvas.itemconfig(myTextLabel,text = json_data["RemainFoods"][1]["Remain"])
    root.after(20, readjson)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1366x768')

myCanvas = Canvas(root, width=1366, height=768)
myCanvas.pack(expand=Y, fill=BOTH)
myTextLabel = myCanvas.create_text(100, 100, text="", anchor="center", font="Calibri 35 bold", fill="black")
myCanvas.update()
myCanvas.after(500,readjson)

root.mainloop()
```

the problem is that the Tkinter opens but when the JSON file is sent, this error comes up:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 839, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\Desktop\epsilon\TestReading\main.py", line 22, in readjson
    json_data = json.loads(readed_file)
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Pouya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Would you please help me to fix that?
Do you think it's better to use the received file directly or save it as a file and then use it?
If there is a more simple way please help me

-Python 3.10 on Windows 10

-I use a USB to Serial converter and I am sure that it is working correctly

Comment: That error means that `readed_file` was an empty string. You could move you debugging effort up to where that string is built. Is it reasonable for it to be empty sometimes?

Comment: I think you could use the received `data` directly without an intermediate file. Its always the same as the file you are writing. But... I don't see anywhere where `readport` is called - or how `readport` would know when its received the entire json file. I think you wait 500 but don't actually read anything from the serial port, hence the error. `readport` should be tasked with notifiying the GUI when its finished reading the json and then `readjson`.

Comment: @tdelaney thanks I forgot about the readport but after doing it nothing change. Would you please help me more in detail?

Comment: `readport` needs a way to know that it has recevied a full json packet. You show pretty-printed json with newlines. Perhaps a terse json withtout newlines, terminated by a newline. Now readport would know a message is done when it sees the first `\n`. Then, put readport in a separate thread. When it reads a full packet, it would decode the json and then post an event/signal/message to tkinter. You would register `readjson` as listener. Then get rid of `myCanvas.after(500,readjson)` because you are now event driven from the `readport` thread.